# No zsh-syntax-highlighting within tmux

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, syntax-highlighting

I experience proper `zsh-syntax-highlighting` (see [here](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting)) when first opening a shell session, but as soon as I enter `tmux`, the syntax highlighting no longer appears.

I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/104) describing a similar but seemingly different problem, as the user is able to see syntax highlighting within the first pane.

I first installed `zsh`, then `oh-my-zsh`, and then finally `zsh-syntax-highlighting` via `pacman` on Arch and sourced it at the bottom of my `.zshrc` (without any conditionals)like so:

`source /usr/share/zsh/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh`

I don't understand why specifically that feature does not seem to work in tmux. All other configurations/themes/plugins/sourced files seem to work well except for this one. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

- The `TERM` variable in `.zshrc` is `export TERM="xterm-256color"`
- Echoing `$TERM` outside tmux gives `xterm-256color`.
- The `TERM` variable in `.tmux.conf` is `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.
- Echoing `$TERM` inside tmux also gives `xterm-256color`.

Comment: What's your `TERM` variable inside and outside of `tmux`?

Comment: See above edit for TERM variables

Comment: Shouldn't `$TERM` be `screen-256color` in tmux? I heard not having properly set the `$TERM` variable can lead to problems in `tmux`. But I don't use `zsh` myself. I also use `screen-256color-s` instead of `screen-256color`, but I don't know what actually the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `TERM` in your shell startup files.  `TERM` is determined by the terminal you're running, not by your shell.

Your shell startup file is overriding the `TERM` set by `tmux`.

Answer (score -1):

I think it was after upgrading to OS El Capitan when this stopped for me. I had this in my ~/.zshrc: `alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color-bce tmux"` (taken from another stackexchange answer).
I changed it to `alias tmux="TERM=screen-256color tmux"` and everything works again now.

I realise that this answer does not help you directly but it might help others.